# Can't access a declared global variable in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

I have the following code:

```
$g_value = 'something';
print "$g_value";

function get_value() {

    global $g_value;
    print $g_value;
}

print get_value();
```

When I run it in a stand-alone PHP script, I get 'somethingsomething'. However, when I run it in a WordPress plugin, I only get 'something'- the global declaration does not make the var accessible in the function. I thought this should always work, and isn't dependent on register_globals or any other environment setting. What's going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
global $g_value;  //declare it global even before assigning it., this should fix it.

$g_value = 'something';
print "$g_value";

function get_value() {

    global $g_value;
    print $g_value;
}

print get_value();
```