# Can't access global variables in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one function define in `function.php`.In this function i declare global variable.i want to access it in my custom plugin `list.php` file.How can I achieve this?

```
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_filter_12', 'filter_timesheet');

function filter_timesheet($form)
{    
    $project=$_POST['input_1'];
    $date=$_POST['input_2'];
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array( 'key' => '9', 'value' => $project );
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array( 'key' => '8', 'value' => $date );
    //$search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array( 'key' => 'created_by', 'value' => $user->ID );
    global $entries; 
    $entries = GFAPI::get_entries(10, $search_criteria );

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: You can use $post instead of $entries

Comment: it return wordpress post data not desired output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access a declared global variable in WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570212/cant-access-a-declared-global-variable-in-wordpress)

Comment: Have you tried to use `$GLOBALS["entries"] = ...` instead of `$entries = ...`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `$post` instead of `$entries` here is a [List](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) of Global Variables

Comment: it return wordpress post data not desired output

Comment: What output you look like?